# $('html').click()... anywhere except one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a dynamically  appended menu which I am removing if you click anywhere on page including the menu links itself. What I am trying to achieve is to prevent the remove if you click a specific link and that simply  does not work for me. Unfortunately I cant use the delegate method, if that would help, due to old version on jquery used on client side, no option to update it.

So maybe you could suggest if there is any way to do so. Here is a quick example of mine.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.menu').append('<a href="" class="solid">Option</a> <a href="">Option</a> <a href="">Option</a>');           
                
        $('.menu a').live('click',function(){
            return false;
        });         

        $('a.solid').live('click',function(){
            return false;
        });

        $('html').click(function() {                    
            $('.menu').remove();                
        });             
                            
        });
</script>
```

and the container

```
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Maybe it will work like this

```
$('html').click(function(e) {                    
   if(!$(e.target).hasClass('solid') )
   {
       $('.menu').remove();                
   }
});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/fq86U/2/

Comment: hehe, this is perfect!!!! Works like a charm and straight forward including with .live('click',function...

Comment: stoppropagation is a better method, but if that is not workable in some way, then this method will work.

Comment: I could ask the question : How I want to do the same behavior if I have children in my container? I don't want to add a class to all the children in the container. Somebody know a solution? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fq86U/74/)

Answer (score 9):

have you tried this:

```
$('.menu a').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Also add event.preventDefault() to stop the operation completely.

Comment: I've tested here and it works, you might be using an odd version of jQuery. If you do `alert(event)` in the click handler of '.menu a', what does it tell you?

Comment: @wouterh ok it works but without LIVE method. In my case it must be ...live('click',function(event){.....   as I would be calling the menu with ajax later. And with LIVE method that does not work.

Comment: what do you mean with 'calling the menu with ajax later' ?

Comment: you can just re-apply the event handler as the new menu data comes in

Comment: I mean that your suggestion does not work if you do it like that
$('.menu a').live('click',function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});

Comment: anyhow, other click events too does not work, like a link inside it

Answer (score 3):

You can also detect clicks on the whole document and check if the current element clicked is your menu element

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if(event.target !== $('.menu')[0]) {
        // hide the menu...
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('html').click(function(e) {

        /* exept elements with class someClass */ 
        if($(e.target).hasClass('someClass')){
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        /* but be carefull the contained links! to be clickable */
        if($(e.target).is('a')){
            return;
        }

        /* here you can code what to do when click on html */

    });
```