# Sliding a div without moving neighbouring content

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, css-animations

I'm trying to create a side bar which will slide in and show the content when a user clicks a button.

the problem that I'm having is when its clicked all the content on the header, body and footer are being moved.

I want the sliding div to slide on top of menu and content without moving it, creating an overlay when clicked

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/tsmpraym/9/

Below is what i have tried so far

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#side").click(function() {
        $('#slidable').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });
    });
})
```

```css
#menu {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
}

#content {
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
}

#side {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #BBB;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#slidable {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    background: #888;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slidable" class="hide">Foobar</div>
<div id="side">+</div>

<div id="menu">
    the menu
</div>
<div id="content">
    content
</div>

<div id="footer">
    the footer
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this setting the position absolute to the slidable element. Check out here: http://jsfiddle.net/tsmpraym/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) { // yep. DOM ready
  
  $("#side").click(function() {
    $('#slidable').toggleClass("open");
  });
  
})
```

```css
body{margin:0;} /* yey? */

#menu {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
#content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}
#side {
  /*float: left; huh? */
  position:absolute; /* add this */
  left:100%;         /* add this */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #BBB;
}
/*.hide { display: none;} */
#slidable {
  /*float: left; why but why */
  position: fixed; /* add this */
  top:0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #888;
  width: 200px;
  right: 100%; /* add this */
  transition: 0.4s;
}
#slidable.open{
  right: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="slidable">
  Foobar
  <div id="side">+</div>
</div>


<div id="menu">
  the menu
</div>
<div id="content">
  content
</div>

<div id="footer">
  the footer
</div>
```

Comment: One issue with the above code is that the "side" button, which is now absolute, will code any content in the "menu" div: http://jsfiddle.net/tsmpraym/30/

Comment: @ErikUggeldahl you better make it absolute like I did, and handle the content spacing differently.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the position absolute and keep available the toggle button too.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#side" ).click(function() {
     $('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'});
     $('#side').toggleClass('keepRight');
      });
  })
```

```css
#menu {
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
}

#footer {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
}

#content {
  background-color:red;
  height:400px;
}
#side{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#BBB;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-timing-function: swing;
}
.keepRight{
  margin-left: 200px;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-timing-function: swing;
}

.hide{
    display:none;
}

#slidable{
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    background:#888;
    width:200px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slidable"class="hide">Foobar</div>
 <div id="side">+</div>
<div id="menu">
the menu
</div>
<div id="content">
content
</div>
   <div id="footer">
    the footer
    </div>
```

Comment: This is a little sloppy, the button slides at a different speed than the menu.  Try putting the button inside the menu Div, give it an absolute positioning and a negative right `margin` (or negative `right` position) to make them slide together without having to animate the button separately.

Comment: @SeanKendle, I know. I just showed the core of the solution. For sure, he would use his transition type and time. Of course, it could be done in other way. The main point was the absolute position

Comment: Voted up for having the first "absolute positioning" answer, although with the caveat that the other answers approach the menu button animation in a cleaner manner - which was outside the scope of the OP's question anyway.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS property `position:absolute;` will have the menu position absolutely on top of other elements. This way it will not re-flow the content of elements beneath it.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

However, in your example, this will cover the button used to open it. You may want to add an interior button to close it.

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsmpraym/27/

Inside the menu div you can add another close button:

```
<div id="slidable"class="hide">Foobar<div id="close">+</div></div>
```

You can add the same properties to it by appending its ID (or refactor into a common class, rather than by ID):

```
#side, #close{
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:#BBB;
}
```

To make it hang off the side, you can make it positioned absolutely with a negative right value:

```
#close {
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:-50px;
}
```

The close button also needs to trigger a toggle:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#side').click(function() {
   $('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'});
  });
  $('#close').click(function() {
   $('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'}); 
  });
});
```

Comment: I usually allow the users to also click anywhere else in the page while the menu is open to close it.  Seems to be a popular feature, as most menus follow that approach.  Just a suggestion!  ^_^

Comment: I was thinking the same as I wrote this, and I agree, it tends to be a good approach.

Seems like this is one solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992368/html-click-anywhere-except-one-element

Comment: I usually go with a click event on body to close the menu, and an `e.stopPropagation()` approach on any elements that I don't want to close the menu.  Cheers!